# White/brown patch on a young monstera leaf - what to do?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, diseases, monstera

I was happy when I saw my *Monstera* growing a new leaf, but recently I noticed a white/brown patch on it and I'm getting worried. What does the patch signify? How can I help the plant?

[image: the new forming leaf has a white patch with a brown patch inside]

Comment: I noticed you are doing pot in pot technique for catch excess water.   After you water, do you let water stay in the white pot or do you dump it out later or do you dump it out right away?    Is there a light source that would hit the new light?

Comment: The white pot is there only for aesthetic reasons. I water the plant moderately once a week and spray it with water each day. There's no excess water. The plant is in a shaded corner of the room, without direct light

Comment: Do you water on a schedule each week?   You should only water when the plant needs water.  When you do water, water until water comes out of the bottom.  Then dump out the extra water.      If you want to create humidity, use a humidifier or place water somewhere near the plant that can evaporate and create humidity that way.   Spraying it good to keep spider mites, but not the best at creating humidity for the entire day.  It only creates humidity for those few minutes.   These kinds of plants want humidity through out the day.

Answer (score 1):

Monstera Deliciosa are an interesting plant in the wild.  They start out as terrestrial plants, but become epiphytic with time.   Their seeds fall down to the ground, where the take root.  The plant will crawl across the ground to the first tree.  At that point it will 'climb' up the side of the tree.  They can grow as tall as the tree 50', so they use specialty roots on the side of the tree to cling itself to the tree, also to capture water from the air and water that runs down the side of the tree.

This means in a pot, they need very well draining soil.  The need to be moist at all times, but the soil needs to be very well drained.  Use indoor potting soil that you add additional drainage matter like perlite.   About 30% of the new mix should be the additional drainage material.  They like rich soil, so adding some compost to the mix will be a nice treat.

Do not water on a schedule.  Water when the top 3-5 cm (1-2") is dry.  Never let the entire pot go dry.  This plant wants constant moisture, but not wet.  Water until water comes out the bottom holes.  Then dump out the excess water out of the catch basin.

I don't know how dark that corner is, but they like bright shade or bright indirect light.